# In the screenshot for live test url in google search console, no texts are visible

Tags: seo, google-search-console

Google Search Console -> URL Inspection -> Test Live URL -> View Tested Page -> Screenshot

I have done a live test in Google search console. When viewing the screenshot of the tested page of my website, it only shows images that i have uploaded in the website page, the text aren't visible in the screenshot.

Does it mean that the crawlers are unable to crawl through my website. What should I do to make the googlebots crawl through the entire page content (text and images)?

Screenshot of the live test -

[image]

Comment: How are your pages generated? What is the actual HTML source in the HTTP response? You need to provide more information.

Comment: I dare to suggest that your problem is related to invalid HTML or script or styles. Without URL, it’s impossible to identify your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some of your media files aren't being loaded. Do you have CSS or Javascript blocked in your `robots.txt`?

Comment: No, my robots.txt doesn't block any css or js code.

Comment: Does screenshot test display the images only, or the text as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your robots.txt is blocking a bunch of css files. Your theme is adding version parameters to them, and your robots.txt disallows URLs with query parameters:

Disallow: /*?*